# "Correct" XML Format / Tree Depth Performance

Tags: xml, tree, depth

I am building an XML file to hold the schedule of a ferry to import into an Android application and have developed three XML tree structures, but looking for an opinion on which to use based on performance and/or correct XML format. The three structures are below and in the end they will be imported into an array that I will search for the next ferry time.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Revised XML Tree - Better?

```
<FerrySchedule>
    <Terminal name="St. George">
        <Schedule day="Monday">
            <DepartureTime>00:00:00</DepartureTime>
            <DepartureTime>01:00:00</DepartureTime>
        </Schedule>
        <Schedule day="TuesdayFriday">
            <DepartureTime>00:00:00</DepartureTime>
            <DepartureTime>00:30:00</DepartureTime>
        </Schedule>
    </Terminal>

    <Terminal name="Whitehall">
        <Schedule day="Monday">
            <DepartureTime>00:30:00</DepartureTime>
            <DepartureTime>01:30:00</DepartureTime>

        </Schedule>
        <Schedule day="TuesdayFriday">
            <DepartureTime>00:00:00</DepartureTime>
            <DepartureTime>00:30:00</DepartureTime>
        </Schedule>
    </Terminal>
</FerrySchedule>
```

---

XML Tree 1:

```
<FerrySchedule>
    <Monday>
        <StGeorge>
            <time>0000</time>
            <time>0100</time>
        </StGeorge>
    </Monday>
</FerrySchedule>
```

XML Tree 2:

```
<FerrySchedule>
    <Monday>
        <boat depart="StGeorge">0000</boat>
        <boat depart="StGeorge">0100</boat>
    </Monday>
</FerrySchedule>
```

XML Tree 3:

```
<FerrySchedule>
    <Monday>
        <boat>
            <depart>St. George</depart>
            <time>0000</time>
        </boat>
        <boat>
            <depart>St. George</depart>
            <time>0100</time>
        </boat>
    </Monday>
</FerrySchedule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely, I think, that performance differences should influence your choice between these designs. However, you haven't said anything about your performance requirements and constraints, so that's just a guess.

I think the main factors that should influence the design are that the meaning should be self-evident to the human reader, that processing the data should be easy, and that generating the data should be easy.

I don't like the look of "Monday" and "StGeorge" as element names. Element names in general should be types, not instances.

I think I would flatten it:

```
<FerrySchedule>
        <boat depart="StGeorge" time="00:00:00" days="Mon"/>
        <boat depart="StGeorge" time="01:00:00" days="Mon Wed Fri"/>
</FerrySchedule>
```

If I were to group the data, I think I would be more likely to group it by departure point rather than by day of the week, but I can't think of a good reason for feeling that way, other than the instinct that schedules for different days of the week are likely to be similar.

The inclusion of seconds in the time value seems slightly ridiculous, but XML Schema's "judiciously chosen" set of data types includes xs:time in hh:mm:ss format, and doesn't include anything in hh:mm format.

Comment: I added one more structure I spoke to a friend about. Just wondering what your thought on it might be. Thanks for your insight about XML, time and attributes vs. elements though -- makes things a bit more clear on organization.